# Electrical Bonding for an exterior building

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, grounding, grounding-and-bonding

I have to upgrade the service I have for an exterior building.
The wiring follows the old code, and I'll need a permit to do it.

So I am going to have to update the service and everything to the newest code regulations, but have a little confusion on the bonding of the ground and neutrals.

Typically you bond the ground and neutral at the first cut off point after the meter, be that a panel or a disconnect.

But the meter and disconnect sit on one building, and the panel and grounding system sit at another building, with about 115feet of distance between them.

From what I understand, in theory, the area that you bond, should also be the entry point for the grounding. (I could be wrong about this though)

Aka my ground should initially enter my disconnect, then bond, then travel the 115 ft to my panel.

But since the grounding point is at the panel, I am not sure how to handle this.

I am not sure if I need to bring my ground wire, straight to the disconnect, then back to the panel.

Or Install a new ground bar at the disconnect, just to do the bonding and then tie the other ground system into it at the disconnect

**Or do it as I have illustrated in the drawing attached**

**(which I believe might be the correct way of handling this)**

which is:

bring the ground into the panel

tie it to the ground bar only

push it back through the conduit to the disconnect
and bond it with the neutral there.

Am I correct in this? or am I missing something?
[image]

Comment: if you have a permit then you also have an inspector to keep happy. ask him/her directly to ensure the anonymous guy on the internet was correct with his advice.

Comment: I agree, however, I haven't been assigned anyone yet.
And either way, I am certainly going to verify the answer, but I am hoping that whoever provides an answer, cites why they believe it is correct. As it will help with deciphering the logic behind it.
Either way, you are right, I need to measure twice so to speak. But some external input will help put my mind at ease when I bring it up later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need a ground wire and ground rods at both structures

You are correct that you only *bond* neutral to ground at the service entrance.  However, current Code not only calls for a grounding wire between the structures (which you have provided), but for a grounding electrode system at *both* buildings.  This can be a concrete-encased electrode (if provided), or the old saw of two 8' ground rods driven 8' apart and connected with an appropriate-gauge wire if no better electrode (such as a concrete-encased electrode, foundation steel of some other sort, or a well casing) exists.

Each grounding electrode system gets a grounding electrode conductor back to the ground bar in the panel/disconnect for the associated structure, and the feeder equipment grounding conductor in the inter-building feeder connects the two together, from ground bar to ground bar.

You are also correct that the radio tower needs a ground rod, and that its ground needs to be bonded to the mains grounding system at the structure where the radio device (transmitter or receiver) is located.  This ground wire goes to a tap on the structure's grounding electrode conductor, made using an intersystem bonding termination device or suitable tap connector.

Comment: I believe you are correct in this.
I was under the impression I would need to hunt down the grounding system and/or install a new one at the service entrance. (I was hoping not)
After a little research, it seems like you are correct and this is indeed code. 
 It requires separate buildings to each have their own grounding system.
It also seems that if you use pvc and if you have nothing that is considered a metallic connection (which includes data, water, etc). you can run everything but ground, but you still need a GEC and in this case you need to re-bond, either way both ends need a GEC

Comment: @ChristopherOrtiz -- no, the exception you are referring to is only valid for existing installation, *not* new work.  IOW: you *must* run the ground wire between the structures for a new feeder, *no exceptions any longer*

Comment: Ah, I seemed to miss that part. But for the sake of being informed on the original question, this is indeed an existing install, tower and all, just a 100 to 200 amp service upgrade using existing piping etc. Only changing a the disconnect, panel, and adding two 50amp outlets that are not illustrated.

Comment: And in addition, just in-case it is relevant to the original question. This service upgrade is a dedicated meter that goes straight to the secondary building in the illustration, only thing it touches on the first building is a disconnect. I dont believe it changes anything, better to mention it than not. Also the tower is decommissioned, but I believe the grounding system still exists for it and hooks into the original panel. The original installation has a similar disconnect (fused however.. I was going to go non fused on this install)  but that original disconnect had no ground/bonding

Comment: I assume it was just done a long time ago and the code was different then o.0. It is rather old, and was a functioning radio tower. now its used (or will be used) as a Kiln  room, for curing pottery. Hence the added 50 amp outlets and service upgrade to handle them along with an old A/c unit that is already installed.  It is an old fire station with the old communications room (hence the big radio tower). Somebody decided to turn it into a learning center, and wants to fire pottery in the old comms room. I appreciate the feed back btw!

Comment: @ChristopherOrtiz -- the upgrade means you have to bring what you are touching up to current code.  However, is there really a need to have a disconnecting means on the first building for the service to the second building, considering that the service to the second building does not pass through the first building, or is the existing service hardware for this service all flush-mounted?

Comment: it is exterior surface mounted, next to a few other meters and disconnects for the services that run the primary building.
I figured with the distance from the meter to the panel (located inside the secondary building, also surface mount but still inside) I was under the impression I need to have a disconnect on the first building. And considering its going to be a kiln room, an exterior disconnect sounds like a good idea if things get "hot" in there. Although I am wondering if I can mount the disconnect onto the second building on the exterior, then I don't have to bother having two grounds?

Comment: If i could do the disconnect on the exterior of the second building that would be nice. It would save a little on the budget, and the second building is basically all concrete block, I think even the roof is poured block, although ill have to double check. Either way, my biggest concern is a kiln bursting into flames for what ever reason. In which case since the building is concrete block, I would think they could cut the sucker off from the outside of the same building fairly safely if they do it in a timely manner. It would have to be one heck of a fire to get through the concrete. but idk

Comment: @ChristopherOrtiz -- if you put the service disconnect on the building served (which needs a main disconnecting means *anyway*), you can then get rid of the first disconnect and simply have a surface-mount meter socket on the first structure, provided the service does not enter the interior of the first structure.  That lets you get rid of the ground wire...

Comment: Cool, that sounds like the most efficient way to handle this.
However, out of curiosity... The original setup, with a panel inside the room and the disconnect on the first building,  That setup would of had a 200 amp main breaker in the panel, which i assume qualifies as the Main disconnecting method? (i did not mention this earlier).

Comment: Also, the original setup looks very similar to what I had originally planned, and since the piping goes underground, I have to assume it makes 4x 90 degree turns down there. In which case, in place of the old disconnect, I think I would do a pull box ?, unless I can shift the meter over somehow so that both the service pipe, and the pipe going to the second building can connect to the meter.. But if i cannot shift the meter enough, and I have to put a pull box or something to avoid reaching over the 4x 90 degree limit, then I am under the impression that I might have to ground that pull box :(

Comment: Which I doubt the meter housing will cover both pipes (unless i dig up the old pipe, then cut and extend it so it reaches o.0  even then its tight). I would think my only other option would be to mount the meter housing sideways, I am not sure this is the best idea (or even code?) as those Nema 3R boxes tend to have some tiny holes in the bottom (near corners and hinges etc), which I always assumed were for drainage, and if they are I doubt they will function as they should? But putting in a much bigger meter housing is going to be tight see  picture attached [link](https://imgur.com/RP1ULR8)

Comment: @ChristopherOrtiz I'd cut the conduit coming out of the bottom of the disconnect down a bit and replace the disconnect with a *conduit body* that can be used to make the turn (a LR, to be precise), as that will supply a pull point just as well as a pull box will while taking up less space

Comment: True, that would be much easier overall. Clearly you have been doing this for a while lol. No grounds to worry about and a straight shot into the meter. Probably my best bet, I can save that ground wire money and rent a small wire puller to get that 3/0 in there with out having any mishaps or visits to the hospital with a pulled/dislocated shoulder.. XD. I appreciate all the feed back, your rock man, If i knew how to give you +rep or something I would lol